# generic messages on careers

Tags: support, jobs

I got my first message on the careers website today. The sender doesn't have a real <strike>company</strike> website yet, and that in itself doesn't bother me.

But:

The message was very generic, it seems the person who sent the message just searched for lots of people with certain tag(s) in the "like" section.

Plus, the company is located in a place that's not listed in my "place I want to work in".

Is this one of intended usages of the careers website?

Comment: Is the employer side of careers still in beta? This could be just somebody trying out the site.

Comment: Don't know, but it didn't seem like a random test. Since it was related to one of the tags in my "like" section.

Answer (score 4):

We are still in a beta period so there may be a few bumps until we get everything working smoothly.

One reason you came up in this particular employers search is due to setting the "Willing to Relocate" to TRUE on your CV.

In the help text it states:

> Is relocation, moving to a different
>   city or country, an option for you? If
>   an employer requires you to move for a
>   job, are you willing to do so?

To keep your name from popping up in global searches where employers aren't particular about searching based on geography, uncheck this and you will only show in employer searches that match the locations you've entered in "Where do you want to work?"

We reserve the right to change how this works in the future as it's obviously not very clear at the moment.

Comment: I might suggest that the ability to move to a different city and work, is entirely independent from the ability to move to a different *country* and work.

Comment: That's not what bothered me, I just cited it as an example that the sender didn't even bother to look at my CV.

Answer (score 2):

> The sender doesn't have a real company
>   yet, and that in itself doesn't bother
>   me.

It bothers me. My understanding was that "employers" would be screened before receiving access to people's private information.

Comment: It could be a startup. As far as I'm concerned, startups are fine, specially if they're composed of talented people who are passionate about programming.